# could someone please give some geometric explanation about $(a+b)^4$?

Tags: geometry, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

This is Visualisation of [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) expansion up to the 4th power

[image]

could someone please give some geometric explanation about $(a+b)^4$, does that move the cube a length of distance? and then compute what?

Comment: $x^4$ is the volume of a $4$-dimensional hypercube which has the length of one side equal to $x$. The image is an attempt to draw this hypercube.

Answer (score 2):

The image is a geoalgebraic construction to verify the formula. The assumption is that a four dimensional cube is simply a three dimensional cube multiplied by a one dimensional segment. As long as the observer accepts that you can fill in the four dimensional cube of side $a+b$ with the ingredients given in the formula the message is conveyed.